# Twelve people travelling in three cars

Tags: combinatorics

I have to solve an introductory counting principles problem, It goes like this:

> > Twelve people travel in three cars, with four people in each car. Each car is driven by its owner. Find the number of ways in which the remaining nine people may be allocated to the cars. **(The arrangement within the car doesn't matter)**

I thought that the nine people have to be grouped into 3 cars where the arrangement doesn't matter, so the answer should be:

> 9C3
>   = 84

But, this is not the right answer. So, how do i solve this?

Comment: Answer. $\binom{9}{3}\cdot\binom{6}{3}=1680$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer should be $(^9C_3 * ^6C_3 * ^3C_3)$ = 1680. 
As first we choose 3 out of 9 and then 3 Out Of remaining 6 and lastly 3 out of 3.

The mistake I did was to take extra care of the dissimilarity of the cars which caused the over-addition.

Explanation
The correct answer is : number of ways to form first group* number of ways to form second group * third group

Any group can occupy any car, if we permute again then it will be a mere repitition.

Multiplication rule : $(^9C_3 * ^6C_3 * ^3C_3)$ 
i.e.
Number of ways of filing first car * number of ways of filing second * number of ways of filing third.

Comment: You already made the assignment of cars to groups! So the final factor of $3!$ is wrong. Try it with two cars, and one passenger per car, if you don't believe me. The answer is $^2C_1 \times ^1C_1 = 2$, not $^2C_1 \times ^1C_1 \times 2! = 4$.

Comment: thanks @TonyK, this answer is wrong. see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1516754/twelve-people-travelling-in-three-cars-clarification-on-existing-answer?noredirect=1#comment3089290_1516754

Comment: @TonyK I am rechecking my assumptions, at my first view I am seeing that you are right. As choosing a group of people from 9 and then 6 and finally from 3 is actually similar to assigning them a car. The mistake I did was that I did over-thinking over the dissimilarity of the cars.

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer is ${9\choose3}\times{6\choose3}$.

$3!$ is not needed as it is already factored in ${9\choose3}\times{6\choose3}$. It's easy to understand if we try with small examples.

Comment: nice................+1 @Kiran