# Twelve people travelling in three cars - clarification on existing answer

Tags: combinatorics

Please refer this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677393/twelve-people-travelling-in-three-cars)

> Twelve people travel in three cars, with four people in each car. Each
>   car is driven by its owner. Find the number of ways in which the
>   remaining nine people may be allocated to the cars. (The arrangement
>   within the car doesn't matter)

Selected answer of this question is ${9\choose3}\times{6\choose3}\times{3\choose3} \times3!$

But I believe this answer includes overcounting also. I think correct answer is ${9\choose3}\times{6\choose3}$ only (reference : explanation provided [here](http://www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=1871#top) for a similar question)

Am I correct here or my understanding is wrong and correct answer is still ${9\choose3}\times{6\choose3}\times{3\choose3} \times3!$?

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Comment: thanks a lot, I spent a lot of time thinking how my understanding is wrong.

Comment: I will be rechecking my assumptions, thanks for pointing a mistake, if there is one :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. 
The mistake I did was to take extra care of the dissimilarity of the cars, thus causing repetitions.

Please check the updated answer, thanks :-)